# how to get text of <h1> tag inside div in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i want text of h1 but how to get it, i dont know, i am new in selenium. Reply me. Thanks in advance. please ignore '\' at start tag of h1 and div.

```
      <\div class="on minimum coverage VPM2" title="This quote includes the minimum coverage levels    required by your state.">      
                <\h1>$74.80/month<\/h1>
            <\/div>
```

Comment: That's not even valid markup. Where's your Selenium code?

Comment: Please use : driver.findElements(By.tagName("h1"))

Comment: but in my HTML page, this is not only single h1 tag, there are many h1 tag, so how can i get this particular h1 tag. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is almost correct but when I had almost exactly the same question, using `getText()` would simply return an empty string. Regardless of whether I tried xpath or CSS to locate the element it made no difference. In fact, the location was a red herring - it was finding the element, it's just the h tag had no text to return.

Try this instead.

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class="on minimum coverage VPM2']/h1")).getAttribute("innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple solution:

```
String titleElem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='on minimum coverage VPM2']/h1")).getAttribute("innerHTML”);

assertEquals("Working as charm", titleElem);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to get the **innerHTML/text of the "h1" tag**, i.e.,**"$74.80/month"** below **java code** will work:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'on minimum coverage VPM2')]/h1")).getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h1")));

WebElement webelem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1"));